# EF 6 Retrieve parent for child autogenerated foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using the following couple of entities:

```
public class Store {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
}

public class Product {
    [product properties here...]
}

public class Promotion : Product {
    [extra promotion properties here...]
}
```

By using Code First it generated my database. It generated a Products table, with a discriminator (in order to discriminate which type of class it is storing) and then a Store_Id foreign key that is filled when it is a Product and another Store_Id1 that is used when using promotions.

Now, after a time, I need to access the store from a specific Promotion. How can it be done? I tried using Fluent and telling it about the Foreign Keys but I failed.

Can you guys bring me some light on this?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't get you database model. You are saying you have a storeId in a product? What if you have the same product in two different stores? I think you need to work more on your model first...

Comment: That is impossible in my case, so it is OK. Anyway, independently of how the model is designed the issue is still there :(

Comment: Show what you've tried in your queries.

Comment: None, I'm using code first with EF6. Thanks jpgrassi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this just a simple many-to-one relationship?

```
public int StoreID { get; set; }
public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
public int Store1ID { get; set; }
public virtual Store Store1 { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Products)
            .WithRequired(m => m.Store);

modelBuilder.Entity<Store>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Promotions)
            .WithRequired(m => m.Store1);
```

`Product.Store` and `Product.Store1` would then just be navigation properties back to their Stores.

Comment: That is the thing!! Thank you so much!

I just changed the required for optional and everything works smooth and the same way. It just renamed some columns and indexs.

Comment: I'm not convinced it'll behave with two relationships between the same tables however. Also, you can probably avoid the renaming using .Map after WithOptional.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you modelling could be improved... `Promotion` should not extend `Product`. You should decouple them, having a promotion point to a product and a store (if you want store specific promotions)... meaning that `Product` and `Store` should be a field in the `Promotion` entity... Expanding a bit further, imagine what would it look like if you want to have a single promotion involving more than one product (e.g.: soap and shampoo, running sneaker and socks, etc...)

Comment: Thanks!That seems a good approach. Either way I'll have the problem accessing the store of a product. I'm just going to try Thomas answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take it into consideration